# store ec2 user data script in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Assuming I am builing ec2 instances using cloudformation, further ec2 having read permission for a given s3 bucket.

Wondering on opinions towards storing user data script in s3? 
In that scenario one would specify in cloudformation user data section of ec2 only the commands "fetch from s3", "make executable" and "execute".

The advantage I see is one can spin up an ec2 manually, do some testing using the script and thereafter reuse same script for building another ec2 without squeezing it into the cloud formation template.

Sure, that way I cannot look at the user data in cloudformation or ec2 console.

Someone sees any other reason why doing so is not a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a common practice, especially when using tools such as Ansible (which pulls scripts from an external store).

As long as the Amazon EC2 instance has an IAM Role that permits access to the file in Amazon S3, it can fetch the file and then execute it.